# What is the input and output impedance of a Widlar current source?

Tags: transistors, bjt, current-source

The Widlar current source is illustrated below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOekjM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The small-signal AC model is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcP4Ww.png)</sup>

I know that if the Early voltage is assumed to be infinite, then the input resistance \$R_{in} = r_{\pi} + \left(\beta + 1\right)R\$. But how does it change (or not change) when the Early voltage is taken into account (i.e., when \$r_{o}\$ is not infinitely large?

Comment: A quick note: The input impedance is simply \$R_{in}=g_{m_1}^{-1}||r_{o}^{1}||R_{in}^{Q_2}\$, where \$R_{in}^{Q_2}=[r_{e_2}+R][\beta+1]\$. If \$r_{o_1}\$ is large compared to \$g_{m_1}^{-1}||R_{in}^{Q_2}\$, then you can neglect it and write \$R_{in} \approx g_{m_1}^{-1}||R_{in}^{Q_2}\$, but since \$R_{in}^{Q_2}\$ is typically large compared to \$g_{m_1}^{-1}\$, the input resistance simply reduces to \$R_{in}\approx g_{m_1}^{-1}\$.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is as described in the following graphic:
[image: This needs to be transcribed, but I don't have the time to do it.]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort. Please note that you can use the schematic drawer tool when you write your answe. Further, Equations can be written as well. Please use these tools when you write any answer/question in the future.